# page not displayafter login with right username and password

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, mysql

[i've use right pass and user, the page address is changed, but the page is not display to home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88XfI.png)

I've tried to delete cookies and history, but it still does not work[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88XfI.png)

Comment: show your relevant code .

Comment: this is a php/mysql question, please remove the other tags from your post

Comment: @JYoThl this is index.php

Comment: look at my code below @SamApostel

Comment: @AlfinNieh this is wildly unclear so please get your problem down to the least lines of code you can, also only post the relevant code

Comment: @Alfin Nieh Don´t include your code as an answer, you must edit your question an upload your code there, this is not the way it works. The answer it´s the space where we give you solutions

Answer (score 0):

this is index.php @JYoThl

```
<?php 

include_once("include.php");
include_once("fungsi.php");

if ($cmd == "logout"){

$runSQL1 = "insert into tb_visitor_history select * from tb_visitor where id_session='$uid'";
$runSQL2 = "delete from tb_visitor where id_session='$uid'";
mysql_query($runSQL1, $connDB);
mysql_query($runSQL2, $connDB);
//header("Location:?menu=$menu&uid=&page=$page");
die("<script> window.parent.location='?menu=$menu&uid=&page=$page'; </script>");
};//if

$logged = 0;
$runSQL = "select count(*) logged from tb_visitor where id_session='$uid'";
$result = mysql_query($runSQL, $connDB);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) { $logged=$row[logged]; };
if (($logged < 1) and ($page <> "home") and ($page <> "")){ 
die("<script> window.parent.location='?menu=$menu&uid=$uid&page=home&haruslogin=1'; </script>");
};//if

$pageAuth = 0;
$REMOTE_ADDR = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"); 
$QUERY_STRING = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
$HTTP_USER_AGENT = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");

if (strpos(" ".strtolower($QUERY_STRING),"_del") > 0){ $pageAuth = 1; };
if (strpos(" ".strtolower($QUERY_STRING),"_upload") > 0){ $pageAuth = 1; };
if (strpos(" ".strtolower($QUERY_STRING),"_add") > 0){ $pageAuth = 1; };

if ($pageAuth == 1){
$runSQL = "select count(*) logged from tb_visitor a, tb_username b, tb_group c where a.id_user=b.id_user and b.id_group=c.id_group and c.kode_group='ADMIN' and a.id_session='$uid'";
$result = mysql_query($runSQL, $connDB);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) { $logged=$row[logged]; }
if ($logged < 1){ 
    $page = str_replace("_del", "", $page);
    $page = str_replace("_upload", "", $page);
    $page = str_replace("_add", "", $page);
    die("<script> window.parent.location='?menu=$menu&uid=$uid&page=$page&unauthorized=1'; </script>");
};//if
};//if

//login reset after 2 hours
$result = mysql_query("select count(*) expired from tb_visitor where (unix_timestamp(now())-unix_timestamp(last_active)) > 7200", $connDB);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $expired = $row[expired]; }
if ($expired > 0) {
mysql_query("insert into tb_visitor_history select * from tb_visitor where (unix_timestamp(now())-unix_timestamp(last_active)) > 7200");
mysql_query("delete from tb_visitor where (unix_timestamp(now())-unix_timestamp(last_active)) > 7200");
};//if
if ($uid <> ""){
$runSQL = "update tb_visitor set status='OPEN', last_active=now(), last_page='$QUERY_STRING', ipaddress='$REMOTE_ADDR' where id_session='$uid'";
$result = mysql_query($runSQL, $connDB);
};//if

//generate uniq code for session
if ($uid == ""){ $uid = uniqid(rand()); }
if ($uid != ""){
$runSQL = "select a.id_user, a.id_group, a.username, a.password, a.fullname, a.email, a.telepon, a.created, a.login_count, a.login_access, a.login_ip, b.last_active, b.last_page from tb_username a, tb_visitor b where a.id_user=b.id_user and b.id_session = '$uid'";
$result = mysql_query($runSQL, $connDB);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $SAH[id_session]  = $uid;
    $SAH[id_user]  = $row[id_user];
    $SAH[id_group] = $row[id_group];
    $SAH[username] = $row[username];
    $SAH[fullname] = $row[fullname];
    $SAH[email]    = $row[email];
    $SAH[telepon]  = $row[telepon];
};//if

//update last_active setiap akses
$runSQL = "update tb_visitor set last_active=now(), last_page='$PAGE_STRING', ipaddress='$REMOTE_ADDR' where id_session='$uid'";
mysql_query($runSQL, $connDB);
};//if

//========//

if ($page == ""){ $page="home"; };
if ($menu == ""){ $menu="1"; }

$INCLUDE_PAGE = $page . ".php";

//halaman menu
unset($htmlMenu, $htmlSubmenu, $i);
$runSQL = "select id_menu, menu, link_menu, urutan from tb_menu order by urutan";
$result = mysql_query($runSQL, $connDB);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
   $i++;
unset($i2, $loadPage);
$runSQL = "select id_submenu, id_menu, submenu, link_submenu from tb_submenu where id_menu='$row[id_menu]' order by id_submenu";
$result2 = mysql_query($runSQL, $connDB);
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array ($result2)) {
    $i2++;
    if ($i2 == 1){ $loadPage = $row2[link_submenu]; }
    if ($menu == $row[id_menu]){
        if ($linkSubmenu <> ""){ $garis = "<font color='#00CCCC'></b>       </font>"; }else{ $garis = ""; };
        $linkSubmenu .= "$garis <li class='active'><a href='?menu=$row[id_menu]&uid=$uid&$row2[link_submenu]'><i class='icon icon-th'></i>  <span> $row2[submenu] </span></a> </li>";
    };//if
};//end-while

if ($htmlMenu <> ""){ $space=" &nbsp; "; }else{ $space=""; };

if ($row['urutan'] == 9) {

    $htmlMenu .= $space ."<li class='' ><a title='' href='?menu=$row[id_menu]&uid=$uid&$loadPage'><i class='icon icon-folder-open'></i> <span class='text'>[2]</span></a></li>";
} else {

    $htmlMenu .= $space ."<li class='' ><a title='' href='?menu=$row[id_menu]&uid=$uid&$loadPage'><i class='icon icon-folder-open'></i>     <span class='text'><b>$row[menu]</b></span></a></li>";
}

};//end-while

if ($linkSubmenu == ""){ $linkSubmenu = "<font color='#003300'>Submenu $row[menu] tidak ada items</font>"; }
?>
<?php 
if (($uid == "")or($logged <= 0)){

include ("login.php");

} else {
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>PT Liza Makmur Mandiri | Inventory</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fullcalendar.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/maruti-style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/maruti-media.css" class="skin-color" />
</head>

<body>

<!--Header-part-->
<div id="header">
    <h1><a href="" style="color:#fff;">INVENTORY SANGGARLIZA</a></h1>
</div>
<!--close-Header-part-->

<!--top-Header-messaages-->
<div class="btn-group rightzero">
    <a class="top_message tip-left" title="Manage Files"><i class="icon-file"></i></a>
    <a class="top_message tip-bottom" title="Manage Users"><i class="icon-user"></i></a>
    <a class="top_message tip-bottom" title="Manage Comments"><i class="icon-comment"></i><span class="label label-important">5</span></a>
    <a class="top_message tip-bottom" title="Manage Orders"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
</div>
<!--close-top-Header-messaages-->

<!--top-Header-menu-->
<div id="user-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <ul class="nav">
        <?=$htmlMenu;?>
            <li class=" dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#menu-messages" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="icon icon-cog"></i>     <span class="text">Opsi</span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="sAdd" title="" href="#"><i class="icon icon-user"></i> <?php echo $SAH[fullname]; ?></a></li>
                    <li><a class="sInbox" title="" href="?menu=<?=$row[id_menu]?>&uid=<?=$uid?>&page=home&cmd=logout"><i class="icon icon-share-alt"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." />
    <button type="submit" class="tip-left" title="Search"><i class="icon-search icon-white"></i></button>
</div>
<!--close-top-Header-menu-->

<div id="sidebar"><a href="#" class="visible-phone"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> Dashboard</a>
    <ul>
        <?=$linkSubmenu;?>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- CONTENT -->
<div id="content">

    <?php include($INCLUDE_PAGE);  ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="footer" class="span12"> 2017 &copy; PT LIZA MAKMUR MANDIRI <a href="http://inventory.sanggarliza.com" style="color:#fff;">Inventory.SanggarLiza.Com</a> </div>
</div>

<script src="assets/js/maruti.chat.js"></script>

<script>
    function formatCurrency(num) {
        num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
        if (isNaN(num))
            num = "0";
        sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
        num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
        cents = num % 100;
        num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
        if (cents < 10)
            cents = "0" + cents;
        for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
            num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + '.' +
            num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
        return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + 'Rp. ' + num);
    }

</script>


</body>

</html>

<?php
}
?>

<? @mysql_close($connDB); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is include.php

```
<?php



$hostserver = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";

$connDB = @mysql_connect($hostserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$connDB2 = @mysql_connect($hostserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, true);

if (!$connDB){ 
    $connDB = @mysql_connect($hostserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword)
or die("System DB Not Stable #1. Report to aasaepul7@gmail.com");
};//if

if (!$connDB2){ 
    $connDB2 = @mysql_connect($hostserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword,true)
or die("System DB Not Stable #1. Report to aasaepul7@gmail.com");
};//if

@mysql_select_db('h67649_inventory', $connDB) or die("System DB Not Stable #2. Report to aasaepul7@gmail.com");
@mysql_select_db('db_liza', $connDB2) or die("System DB Not Stable #2. Report to aasaepul7@gmail.com");

  //redirect parent location
function redirect($goto = 'index.php'){
    mysql_close();
    return die("<script> window.parent.location='$goto'; </script>");
}

  //redirect close and open new windows
function closeOpenNew($goto = 'index.php', $name = 'operator', $width = '550', $height = '373'){
    mysql_close();
    $view  = "<script language='JavaScript'>";
    $view .= "a=open('$goto', '$name', \"toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=$width,height=$height\");";
    $view .= "a.focus();";
    $view .= "win = top;  win.opener = top;  win.close(); ";
    $view .= "</script>";
return die($view);
}

//calculate page view
function pageViewRecord ($pnum, $totalRecord, $pageLink, $listRecord = 10) {
global $pnum, $totalRecord, $beginPage, $endPage, $totalPage, $offsetRecord, $pnumlink;

if (!isset($pnum)) { $pnum=1; };
if (!isset($listRecord)) { $listRecord=10; };
if ($totalRecord>0) {
    $totalPage = intval($totalRecord / $listRecord);
    if (($totalRecord % $listRecord)<>0) { $totalPage++;};
    $offsetRecord=($pnum-1) * $listRecord;
        $limitPage=10;
        if ($pnum>$totalPage){$pnum=$totalPage;};
        $nextPage = intval($pnum/$limitPage);
        if (($pnum % $limitPage)<>0) {$nextPage++;};
        //$beginPage = (($nextPage-1)*$limitPage)+1;
        $beginPage = $pnum - ( intval($limitPage/2) );
        if ($beginPage <= 0) { $beginPage = 1; };
        //$endPage = $nextPage*$limitPage;
        $endPage = $pnum + ( intval($limitPage/2) );
        if ($endPage - $beginPage < $limitPage) { $endPage = $endPage + ($limitPage - ($endPage - $beginPage) - 1); }
        if ($endPage>$totalPage) {$endPage=$totalPage;};
}else{
    $listRecord=0;
    $offsetRecord=0;
};  
$beginLINK = "<a href='".$pageLink; 
$endLINK = "' style='text-decoration:none'>";
if ($beginPage>1) { $pnumlink .= $beginLINK ."1". $endLINK . "<b>�</b></a>&nbsp;"; }
if ($pnum>1) { $pnumlink .= $beginLINK . ($pnum-1) . $endLINK . "<b>�</b></a>"; };
for ($hit=$beginPage; $hit<=$endPage; $hit++){
  if($pnum==$hit) {$pnumlink.="<font color='#FF0000'><b>&nbsp;".$hit."&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></font>";}
  else {$pnumlink.="&nbsp;".$beginLINK.$hit.$endLINK.$hit."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>";};
}; 
if ($pnum<$totalPage){ $pnumlink.=$beginLINK.($pnum+1).$endLINK."<b>�</b></a>"; };
if ($endPage<$totalPage){ $pnumlink.="&nbsp;".$beginLINK.$totalPage.$endLINK."<b>�</b></a>"; };
if ($totalPage == 0){ $pnumlink = "<b>0</b>"; };
return $pnumlink;
}

function decimal($number){
$tmp = explode(".",$number);
if (count($tmp) > 0) { $number = $tmp[0] .".". substr($tmp[1],0,2); };
return $number;
}

include_once("tanggal.php");
function getDay($tgl, $bln, $thn){
global $hari;
$num_hari = date("w", mktime (0,0,0,$bln,$tgl,$thn));
return $hari[$num_hari];
};//getDay

function getMon($bln){
global $bulannum, $bulan;
for ($i=0; $i<count($bulan); $i++){
    if ($bulannum[$i] == $bln) { $nama_bln = $bulan[$i]; break; }
};//for
return $nama_bln;
};//getMon

function currency($number){
/*
$rrr = substr($number,-3);  $sisa = str_replace($rrr);
//$tmp = explode(".",$sisa);
//if (count($tmp) > 0) { $number = $tmp[0] .".". substr($tmp[1],0,2); };
$digit = strlen($number);
for ($ii=$digit; $ii>=3; $ii=$ii-3){
    $belakang = substr($number,-3);  $number = substr($number,0, $ii);
    if ($currency <> ""){ $currency="$currency.$belakang"; }else{ $currency=$belakang; }
};
if ($number <> ""){ $currency="$number.$currency"; }
*/
return $number;
};//end-decimal

function ribuan($number){
$digit = strlen($number);
if ($number > 999){
    if ($digit > 6){ $number = round($number/1000000,2)."jt"; }
    else if ($digit > 3){ $number = round($number/1000,1)."rb"; };
};//if
return $number;
};//end-ribuan

function findPhone($phone_number) {
global $connDB, $databaseSMS;

return "Unregister";
};//end-function-findPhone


  //setting parameter web
$result = mysql_query("select variable,value from tb_settings", $connDB);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) { 
$row[value] = addslashes($row[value]);
$variable = "\$".$row[variable]."=\"".$row[value]."\";";
eval($variable);
};//while



function create_dd($id,$val=array(),$q){
$result=  mysql_query($q, $connDB);
$x=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) { 
    $array[]=array($val[0]=>$row[$val[0]],$val[1]=>$row[$val[1]]);
$x++; }
$html="<select name='$id' id='$id'>";
foreach($array as $rw){
    $html.="<option value='".$rw[$val[0]]."'>";
    $html.=$rw[$val[1]];
    $html.="</option>";
}
$html.="</select>";
return  $html;
}



function pre($sql){
echo "<pre>".print_r($sql,true)."</pre>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is home.php

```
<div id="content-header">
<div id="breadcrumb"> 
<a href="" title="Go to Home" class="tip-bottom"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="quick-actions_homepage">
<ul class="quick-actions">
  <li> <a href="?menu=<?=$menu;?>&uid=<?=$uid;?>&page=<?=$page;?>"> <i class="icon-dashboard"></i> Dashboard </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="?menu=<?=$menu;?>&uid=<?=$uid;?>&page=p_katalog_list"> <i class="icon-book"></i> Data Katalog </a> </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="widget-box">
  <div class="widget-title"><span class="icon"><i class="icon-tasks"></i></span>
    <h5>Site Analytics</h5>
    <div class="buttons"><a href="#" class="btn btn-mini btn-success"><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Update status</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="widget-content">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span8">
        <div class="chart"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
        <ul class="stat-boxes2">
          <li>
            <div class="left peity_bar_neutral"><span><span style="display: none;">2,4,9,7,12,10,12</span>
              <canvas width="50" height="24"></canvas>
              </span>+10%
            </div>
            <div class="right"> <strong>15598</strong> Visits </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="left peity_line_neutral"><span><span style="display: none;">10,15,8,14,13,10,10,15</span>
              <canvas width="50" height="24"></canvas>
              </span>10%
            </div>
            <div class="right"> <strong>150</strong> New Users </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="left peity_bar_bad"><span><span style="display: none;">3,5,6,16,8,10,6</span>
              <canvas width="50" height="24"></canvas>
                </span>-40%
            </div>
            <div class="right"> <strong>4560</strong> Orders</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="left peity_line_good"><span><span style="display: none;">12,6,9,13,14,10,17</span>
              <canvas width="50" height="24"></canvas>
              </span>+60%
            </div>
            <div class="right"> <strong>936</strong> Register </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="assets/js/excanvas.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.custom.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.flot.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.peity.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/maruti.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/maruti.dashboard.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// This function is called from the pop-up menus to transfer to
// a different page. Ignore if the value returned is a null string:
function goPage (newURL) {

  // if url is empty, skip the menu dividers and reset the menu selection to default
  if (newURL != "") {

      // if url is "-", it is this page -- reset the menu:
      if (newURL == "-" ) {
          resetMenu();            
      } 
      // else, send page to designated URL            
      else {  
        document.location.href = newURL;
      }
  }
}
 // resets the menu selection upon entry to this page:
 function resetMenu() {
 document.gomenu.selector.selectedIndex = 2;
 }
 </script>
```